# In D3, how can I select specific children elements of current node in zoomable treemap?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to access children nodes of currently zoomed in cell in D3 zoomable Treemap. Specifically, I'd like to replace the `href` attribute in nested `image` nodes.

Is there a way of selecting just the children elements of the current node inside `function zoomed(d){}`, ideally without filtering the whole treemap, i.e. by utilising `node.children` property?

Something like this:

```
function zoomed(d) {

  // get children nodes data
  const currentChildren = d.children; // [Zh, Zh, Zh] - ok

  // select all children of current node
  // and select their image nodes
  // then update href attribute
  d3.select(this)
    .select(d => d.children)
    .selectAll("image")
    .attr("href", d => "/img/" + d.data.image);

}
```

Each cell structure is this:

```
g
  rect
  clipPath
  svg
    image
```